# Using xmodmap automatically after login

Tags: 13.10, xmodmap

Every time i reboot or start my computer, ubuntu 13.10 looses my xmodmap.
I have to type:

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

and the mapping works.
How can I have this xmodmap automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Unity dash and type  as startup applications and open it.

Then click at add button and add the

- Name as `xmodmap`
- command as `xmodmap .Xmodmap`

click at Ok button.

thats it , from next time it will autostart.
For example look at the image [image]

Answer (score -2):

The above didn't work for me with Unity 13.10 fresh install.

I had to tweak it a bit

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
xmodmap .Xmodmap &
exit 0
```